# How do you create an NPM package written in Typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, read-eval-print-loop, typescript-typings

I have spent a couple days not trying to figure out how to build a npm package with typescript. I can't seem to get anything up and running. Do I need a module loader like webpack and gulp?

What do I do about modules that have not @types like co, co-prompt. I see everyone talk about d.ts files but in all the typescript github repos I don't see any examples of these files or how they are implemented. I am not writing anything to do with the front end. This is strictly a repl and I am having trouble just getting the light to turn on with this project.